# How to generate a Mandelbrot with T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, code-golf, fractals

Learning a little about T-SQL, and thought an interesting exercise would be to generate a Mandelbrot set with it.

Turns out someone already has (and recently, it appears).  I'll let someone else post it as an answer, but I'm curious what optimizations can be made.

Alternately, what would you do to make the code more readable?

I'll select the most readable (yet reasonably compact) version as the accepted answer (too bad we don't have rep bounties yet!) unless someone really comes along with a great optimization.

Bonus points to those answers that teach me a little something about T-SQL.

-Adam

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Create PROCEDURE dbo.mandlebrot
@left float,
@right float,
@Top float,
@Bottom float,
@Res float,
@MaxIterations Integer = 500
As
Set NoCount On

Declare @Grid Table (
    X float Not Null, 
    Y float Not Null,
    InSet Bit
   Primary Key (X, Y))

Declare @Xo float, @Yo float, @Abs float
Declare @PtX Float, @PtY Float
Declare @Iteration Integer Set @Iteration = 0
Select @Xo = @Left, @Yo = @Bottom

While @Yo <= @Top Begin
    While @Xo <= @Right Begin
        Select @PtX = @Xo, @PtY = @Yo
        While @Iteration < @MaxIterations 
            And (Square(@PtX) + Square(@PtY)) < 4.0 Begin
            Select @PtX = Square(@PtX) - Square(@PtY) + @Xo,
                   @PtY = 2* @PtX * @PtY + @Yo
            Select @Iteration, @PtX, @PtY
            Set @Iteration = @Iteration + 1
        End
        Insert @Grid(X, Y, InSet) 
        Values(@Xo, @Yo, Case 
            When @Iteration < @MaxIterations
                    Then 1 Else 0 End)
        Set @Xo = @Xo + @res
        Set @Iteration = 0
    End
    Select @Xo = @Left, 
           @Yo = @Yo + @Res
End

Select * From @Grid
```

Answer (score 14):

From [thedailywtf.com](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Stupid-Coding-Tricks-The-TSQL-Madlebrot.aspx)

```
-- AUTHOR: GRAEME JOB
-- CREATED: 12-OCT-2008
-- BECAUSE: SINGLE SQL COMMAND < 50 LINES. JUST BECAUSE.
WITH 
      XGEN(X, IX) AS (              -- X DIM GENERATOR
            SELECT CAST(-2.2 AS FLOAT) AS X, 0 AS IX UNION ALL
            SELECT CAST(X + 0.031 AS FLOAT) AS X, IX + 1 AS IX
            FROM XGEN
            WHERE IX < 100
      ),
      YGEN(Y, IY) AS (              -- Y DIM GENERATOR
            SELECT CAST(-1.5 AS FLOAT) AS Y, 0 AS IY UNION ALL
            SELECT CAST(Y + 0.031 AS FLOAT) AS Y, IY + 1 AS IY
            FROM YGEN
            WHERE IY < 100
      ),
      Z(IX, IY, CX, CY, X, Y, I) AS (           -- Z POINT ITERATOR
            SELECT IX, IY, X, Y, X, Y, 0
            FROM XGEN, YGEN   
            UNION ALL
            SELECT IX, IY, CX, CY, X * X - Y * Y + CX AS X, Y * X * 2 + CY, I + 1
            FROM Z
            WHERE X * X + Y * Y < 16
            AND I < 100
      )
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
      REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
      REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
      (X0+X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+X6+X7+X8+X9+X10+X11+X12+X13+X14+X15+X16+X17+X18+X19+
      X20+X21+X22+X23+X24+X25+X26+X27+X28+X29+X30+X31+X32+X33+X34+X35+X36+X37+X38+X39+
      X40+X41+X42+X43+X44+X45+X46+X47+X48+X49+X50+X51+X52+X53+X54+X55+X56+X57+X58+X59+
      X60+X61+X62+X63+X64+X65+X66+X67+X68+X69+X70+X71+X72+X73+X74+X75+X76+X77+X78+X79+
      X80+X81+X82+X83+X84+X85+X86+X87+X88+X89+X90+X91+X92+X93+X94+X95+X96+X97+X98+X99),
      'A',' '),   'B','.'),   'C',','),   'D',','),   'E',','),   'F','-'),   'G','-'),
      'H','-'),   'I','-'),   'J','-'),   'K','+'),   'L','+'),   'M','+'),   'N','+'),
      'O','%'),   'P','%'),   'Q','%'),   'R','%'),   'S','@'),   'T','@'),   'U','@'),
      'V','@'),   'W','#'),   'X','#'),   'Y','#'),   'Z',' ')
FROM (
      SELECT 'X' + CAST(IX AS VARCHAR) AS IX,
      IY,   SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ISNULL(NULLIF(I, 0), 1), 1) AS I
      FROM Z) ZT
PIVOT (
      MAX(I) FOR IX IN (
      X0,X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X7,X8,X9,X10,X11,X12,X13,X14,X15,X16,X17,X18,X19,
      X20,X21,X22,X23,X24,X25,X26,X27,X28,X29,X30,X31,X32,X33,X34,X35,X36,X37,X38,X39,
      X40,X41,X42,X43,X44,X45,X46,X47,X48,X49,X50,X51,X52,X53,X54,X55,X56,X57,X58,X59,
      X60,X61,X62,X63,X64,X65,X66,X67,X68,X69,X70,X71,X72,X73,X74,X75,X76,X77,X78,X79,
      X80,X81,X82,X83,X84,X85,X86,X87,X88,X89,X90,X91,X92,X93,X94,X95,X96,X97,X98,X99)
) AS PZT
```

[image: Here's the result]
<sub>(source: [thedailywtf.com](http://img.thedailywtf.com/images/200811/madlebrot.png))</sub>

Comment: Sorry, meant to include the picture of what it looks like.

Comment: Reminds me of the time in the 1987-1992 timeframe when somebody wrote a Mandelbrot generator in PostScript, and some idiot kept sending it to our companies one and only LaserWriter.

Comment: @paul - Hilarious!  Laser printer hijinks at my workplace were limited to changing the status message on the HP printers.

Comment: Now that it's 2022, the only adjustment I'd make to this awesome code is to replace all the `REPLACE` calls with a [`TRANSLATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) call: `TRANSLATE((X0+...+X99), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ' .,,,-----++++%%%%@@@@### ')`

Answer (score 7):

Hopefully, this teaches a bit about T-SQL as well, It does everything in a set based approach which is TSQL's strength (i.e. no while loops) or variables:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

--populate
;WITH Numbers ([row]) AS
(
   SELECT TOP 100 CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS FLOAT) [row]
   FROM sys.columns
)
SELECT A.row AS x, 
   B.row AS y, 
   0 AS iter, 
   A.row AS iterx, 
   B.row AS itery, 
   '.' AS symbol
INTO #GRID
FROM Numbers A, Numbers B
WHERE B.[row] <= 24
GO

-- scale
UPDATE #GRID
SET x = x * 3.0 / 100.0 - 2,
   y = y * 2.0 / 24.0 - 1,
   iterx = x * 3.0 / 100.0 - 2,
   itery = y * 2.0 / 24.0 - 1
GO

--iterate
UPDATE #GRID
SET iterx = iterx*iterx - itery*itery + x,
    itery = 2*iterx*itery + y,
    iter = iter+1
WHERE iterx*iterx+itery*itery <= 2*2
GO 257

UPDATE #GRID SET symbol = CHAR(64+(iter%26)) WHERE NOT iter = 257
GO

--print
WITH concatenated (y, c) AS 
(
   SELECT G2.y,
       (SELECT SUBSTRING(G.symbol, 1, 1) AS [data()] FROM #GRID G WHERE G.y = G2.y FOR XML PATH('')) c
   FROM (SELECT DISTINCT y FROM #GRID) AS G2
)
SELECT REPLACE(c, ' ', '') FROM concatenated ORDER BY y
GO


DROP TABLE #GRID
```

Comment: Haha, nice trick "no loops or variables", except for the "GO 257", which is essentially a loop. Still pretty cool though.

Answer (score 3):

```
with points (x1,y1,x2,y2,depth) as
(
    select convert(float,-2.40), convert(float,-2.40), convert(float,2.40), convert(float,2.40), 8
    union all select x1,y1,(x1+x2)/2,(y1+y2)/2,depth-1 from points where depth>0
    union all select (x1+x2)/2,y1,x2,(y1+y2)/2,depth-1 from points where depth>0
    union all select x1,(y1+y2)/2,(x1+x2)/2,y2,depth-1 from points where depth>0
    union all select (x1+x2)/2,(y1+y2)/2,x2,y2,depth-1 from points where depth>0
),
mandelbrot(x1,y1,x2,y2,x,y,depth) as
(
    select x1,y1,x2,y2,convert(float,0),convert(float,0),20 from points where depth=0
    union all
    select x1,y1,x2,y2, x*x-y*y+x1, 2*x*y+y1,depth-1 from mandelbrot where depth > 0 and (x*x+y*y<4)
)
select geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((' +
  convert(varchar,x1) + ' ' + convert(varchar,y1) + ',' +
  convert(varchar,x1) + ' ' + convert(varchar,y2) + ',' +
  convert(varchar,x2) + ' ' + convert(varchar,y2) + ',' +
  convert(varchar,x2) + ' ' + convert(varchar,y1) + ',' +
  convert(varchar,x1) + ' ' + convert(varchar,y1) + '))',0)
  from mandelbrot where depth = 0
```